# Resolution and Print size change when converting

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am converting a file from TIff to Jpeg and one out of 133 is changing the resolution and print size.

The original resolution is 300 × 300 ppi and the original print size is 3.727 × 1.880 inches.

But when I convert it goes to 72 × 72 ppi and print size to 15.528 × 7.833 inches.

Is there a way to force it to keep the same resolution?

Comment: Please, post some code you are using.

Comment: I'm thinking, most probably the answer is *Yes*. You might want to elaborate on the question a bit, to get a more precise answer. ;-)